# How to get the Index of a <ul> list and select a random option automatically

Tags: c#, list, selenium

I'm unable to select the items of a  tag list, all the options listed in

. Basically I need to know the quantity of items and select one (any). The current code is not able to select do to i'm unable to find the correct index, and i have to search a correct index manually

I tried using a For each element in the list throw

How I search the index and option displayed:

```
foreach (var a in nameoflist)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ddm" + a.Text);
            }
```

How I select the items in the list:

```
List<IWebElement> dropDownMenu = driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("dropdown-menu"));
IList<IWebElement> selectdomain = dropDownMenu[0].FindElements(By.TagName("li"));
selectdomain[0].Click();
```

External HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scope" ng-class="{'closed-typeahed' : !isOpen()}" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" role="listbox" aria-hidden="false" uib-typeahead-popup="" id="typeahead-1511-7724" matches="matches" active="activeIdx" select="select(activeIdx, evt)" move-in-progress="moveInProgress" query="query" position="position" assign-is-open="assignIsOpen(isOpen)" debounce="debounceUpdate" popup-template-url="typeahead-custom-popup.html" style="top: 34px; left: 0px;">
            <!-- ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-0">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="csv.user03@coreviewlab.com">csv.<strong>user</strong>03@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-1">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="csv.user@coreviewlab.com">csv.<strong>user</strong>@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-2">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="synch.user7@coreviewlab.com">synch.<strong>user</strong>7@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope active" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-3">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="hybrid.usermodified@coreviewlab.com">hybrid.<strong>user</strong>modified@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-4">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="csv.user02@coreviewlab.com">csv.<strong>user</strong>02@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-5">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="csve.user04@coreviewlab.com">csve.<strong>user</strong>04@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-6">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="csve.user05@coreviewlab.com">csve.<strong>user</strong>05@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-7">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="testuser.01@coreviewlab.com">test<strong>user</strong>.01@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-8">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="carmine.syncuser@coreviewlab.com">carmine.sync<strong>user</strong>@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index --><li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-9">
                <a href="" tabindex="-1" ng-bind-html="match.label | uibTypeaheadHighlight:query" ng-attr-title="{{match.label}}" class="ng-binding ng-scope" title="newhybrid.user@coreviewlab.com">newhybrid.<strong>user</strong>@coreviewlab.com</a>
            </li><!-- end ngRepeat: match in matches track by $index -->
            <li><div class="typeahead-no-results small ng-hide" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label == '')"><span translate="" class="ng-scope">No result found</span></div></li>
        </ul>
```

HTML of li

```
<li class="uib-typeahead-match ng-scope" ng-show="isOpen() &amp;&amp; !moveInProgress &amp;&amp; (matches[0] &amp;&amp; matches[0].label != '')" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index, $event)" role="option" id="typeahead-1511-7724-option-0">
```

I always receive the "Index out of range" error., and i have to manually search a valid Index. How can i do to select any option automatically?

Comment: please share you html

Comment: I update the question

Comment: have you tried using byClassName("dropdown-menu ng-isolate-scopef")?

Comment: the issue is not that I'm unable to find the items in the UL, but I'm unable to select them, you could say the error is only in the indexing numbers. Not classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put count validation first

```
IList<IWebElement> selectdomain = dropDownMenu[0].FindElements(By.TagName("li"));

var count = selectdomain.Count();
if (count > 0){
    selectdomain[0].Click();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't select a random option as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used selenium but you can try the below:

```
// Get ul.dropdown-menu > li
List<WebElement> dropdownMenuItems = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-menu']/li")); 

// Get Quantity
int quantity = dropdownMenuItems.Count;

// Create instance of random
Random rnd = new Random();

// Get a random index between 0 and the max being list length
int randomIndex = rnd.Next(quantity); 

// Get the list item from the random index
var randomListItem = dropdownMenuItems[randomIndex];

// Click the element
randomListItem.Click();


// Optiona: Loop through items
foreach (var listItem in dropdownMenuItems)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ddm" listItem a.Text);
}
```